AWS KMS Key Created by CloudFormation Immediately Enters Pending Deletion State
Background
I'm running a bash script to set up AWS Roles Anywhere using a KMS key created via a CloudFormation stack. The script first deploys the KMS key, then uses it to sign a Certificate Authority (CA). However, I’m encountering an issue where the KMS key immediately enters a pending deletion state right after it's created, causing subsequent operations to fail.
Here’s the relevant part of my script:
openrolesanywhere admin accept-request --request-file ./key.csr --validity-duration 8760h --serial-number 2 --common-name Codespaces --organization DevOpStar

The error message indicates that when trying to initialize the KMS signer and retrieve the public key for signing, the KMS key is in a pending deletion state:
Error: initializing kms signer: getting public key: operation error KMS: GetPublicKey, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 93e5602a-b20f-4370-86fe-77dc38f87e0c, KMSInvalidStateException: arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:12222222:key/25e4e095-b082-4193-bb98-e96a9f0e3bed is pending deletion.

Despite the key being freshly created, it seems to be in a pending deletion state immediately after creation.
Here is the full script
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

# Set the working directory
WORKING_DIR="/workspaces/test_openroles"

# Variables (you can pass these as parameters or set them here)
ROLE_NAME=${1:-"rolefoo"}
SESSION_DURATION=${2:-"3600s"}
SERIAL_NUMBER=${3:-2}
COMMON_NAME=${4:-"Codespaces"}
ORGANIZATION=${5:-"MyOrganization"}
VALIDITY_DURATION=${6:-"8760h"}

# Clone and install openrolesanywhere client
if [ -e /tmp/openrolesanywhere ]; then
  rm -rf /tmp/openrolesanywhere
fi
git clone https://github.com/aidansteele/openrolesanywhere.git /tmp/openrolesanywhere
cd /tmp/openrolesanywhere/cmd/openrolesanywhere
go install .

cd $WORKING_DIR

# AWS region and stack names
REGION="us-east-1"
KMS_STACK_NAME="openrolesanywhere-kmfoobar"
ROLE_STACK_NAME="openrolesanywhere-kmfoobar"

# Deploy KMS key
aws cloudformation deploy \
    --region $REGION \
    --template-file "$WORKING_DIR/kms.yml" \
    --stack-name $KMS_STACK_NAME

# Get KMS Key ID
KMS_KEY_ID=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
    --stack-name "$KMS_STACK_NAME" \
    --region $REGION \
    --query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`KeyId`].OutputValue' \
    --output text)

# Check if the KMS key is in a pending deletion state and cancel deletion if so
EXISTING_KEY_STATUS=$(aws kms describe-key --key-id $KMS_KEY_ID --region $REGION --query 'KeyMetadata.KeyState' --output text 2>/dev/null || echo "NotFound")

if [ "$EXISTING_KEY_STATUS" == "PendingDeletion" ]; then
  echo "KMS key $KMS_KEY_ID is pending deletion. Canceling deletion..."
  aws kms cancel-key-deletion --key-id $KMS_KEY_ID --region $REGION
fi

# Create Certificate Authority (CA)
openrolesanywhere admin create-ca \
    --name openrolesanywhere-trust \
    --kms-key-id $KMS_KEY_ID \
    --validity-duration $VALIDITY_DURATION \
    --serial-number 1 \
    --common-name $COMMON_NAME \
    --organization $ORGANIZATION

# Deploy Role Stack
aws cloudformation deploy \
    --region $REGION \
    --template-file "$WORKING_DIR/role.yml" \
    --stack-name $ROLE_STACK_NAME \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM

# Get the Role ARN
S3_EXAMPLE_ROLE=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
    --region $REGION \
    --stack-name "$ROLE_STACK_NAME" \
    --query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`RoleArn`].OutputValue' \
    --output text)

# Create Roles Anywhere Profile
openrolesanywhere admin create-profile \
    --name $ROLE_NAME \
    --session-duration $SESSION_DURATION \
    --role-arn $S3_EXAMPLE_ROLE

# Start the SSH agent
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

# Create a private key for signing
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=~/.ssh/id_rsa_codespaces
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH -C "user@example.com" -N ""

# Add private key to SSH agent
ssh-add $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH

# Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)
SSH_FINGERPRINT=$(ssh-add -l | awk '{print $2}')
CSR_PATH=./key.csr
openrolesanywhere request-certificate \
    --ssh-fingerprint $SSH_FINGERPRINT > $CSR_PATH

# Accept CSR and generate certificate
CERT_PATH=./codespaces.pem
openrolesanywhere admin accept-request \
    --request-file $CSR_PATH \
    --validity-duration $VALIDITY_DURATION \
    --serial-number $SERIAL_NUMBER \
    --common-name $COMMON_NAME \
    --organization $ORGANIZATION > $CERT_PATH

# Store generated certificates in ~/.config/openrolesanywhere/
mkdir -p ~/.config/openrolesanywhere
cp $CERT_PATH ~/.config/openrolesanywhere/codespaces.pem

# Create AWS credential process script
sudo tee /opt/roles-anywhere-handler << END
#!/bin/bash
eval "\$(ssh-agent -s)" > /dev/null
ssh-add $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH > /dev/null
openrolesanywhere credential-process --name $ROLE_NAME --role-arn $S3_EXAMPLE_ROLE
END

# Make the handler executable
sudo chmod +x /opt/roles-anywhere-handler

# Configure AWS CLI to use the credential process
mkdir -p ~/.aws
tee ~/.aws/config << END
[profile default]
credential_process = /opt/roles-anywhere-handler
region = $REGION
END

# Output the file values before cleanup
echo "ROLES_ANYWHERE_CERTIFICATE:"
cat ~/.config/openrolesanywhere/codespaces.pem

echo "ROLES_ANYWHERE_ROLE:"
echo $S3_EXAMPLE_ROLE

echo "SSH_PRIVATE_SIGNING_KEY:"
cat $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH

echo "CA Certificate:"
cat ~/.config/openrolesanywhere/ca.pem

echo "Profile ARN:"
cat ~/.config/openrolesanywhere/profile-arn.txt

echo "Trust Anchor ARN:"
cat ~/.config/openrolesanywhere/trust-anchor-arn.txt

echo "Setup complete. Test with 'aws sts get-caller-identity'"

# Cleanup
echo "Cleaning up..."

# Remove the openrolesanywhere Go installation
rm -rf /tmp/openrolesanywhere

# Remove ~/.config/openrolesanywhere folder
rm -rf ~/.config/openrolesanywhere

# Remove the generated SSH private key and public key
rm -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_codespaces ~/.ssh/id_rsa_codespaces.pub

echo "Cleanup complete."


I’ve tried ensuring that the stack names are unique and added checks to cancel deletion if the key is in the pending deletion state, but the issue persists. I’ve also checked the KMS key status immediately after creation, and it confirms that the key is in a pending deletion state.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any suggestions on what might be causing this behavior?


My overall objective was to create a bash script for this [article][1] i found which helps with using AWS IAM Roles Anywhere by setting it up for use inside GitHub Codespaces.


  [1]: https://devopstar.com/2022/08/01/github-codespaces-and-iam-roles-anywhere/


I'm unsure of what may cause the key to be scheduled for deletion, but the CloudTrail logs for that KMS key might be helpful to identify it.
# Replace with your KMS Key ID
export KMS_KEY_ID="abcdef12-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-..."
aws cloudtrail lookup-events  \
  --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=ResourceName,AttributeValue=$KMS_KEY_ID

The CloudTrail logs themselves are nested in the response as a string, so you can parse them out by piping to jq '.Events[].CloudTrailEvent | fromjson.
For example, here is one of my logs:
{
  "eventVersion": "1.09",
  "userIdentity": {
    "type": "AssumedRole",
    "principalId": "<iam-role-session-name>",
    "arn": "arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_PowerUserAccess_<full-role-name>",
    "accountId": "<account>",
    # Removed some content
  },
  "eventTime": "2024-07-23T17:53:09Z",
  "eventSource": "kms.amazonaws.com",
  "eventName": "ScheduleKeyDeletion",
  "awsRegion": "us-west-1",
  "sourceIPAddress": "<ip>",
  "userAgent": "APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/1.7.5 (+https://www.terraform.io) terraform-provider-aws/5.40.0 (+https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws) aws-sdk-go/1.50.33 (go1.21.7; darwin; arm64)",
  "requestParameters": {
    "pendingWindowInDays": 7,
    "keyId": "<kms-key-id>"
  }
  # Removed some content
}

From this output, I now know that this KMS key was scheduled to be deleted by someone using AWSReservedSSO_PowerUserAccess and running Terraform.
(Not an answer - I don't have the reputation to comment)
